# How to apply Cases on multiple parts of sublists?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, filtering

I have the following data

```
sol={{2063, 853}, {2066, 855}, {2069, 857}, {2072, 859}}
```

I can find prime-pairs by

```
Select[sol, PrimeQ[#[[1]]] && PrimeQ[#[[2]]] &]
```

yielding

```
{{2063, 853}, {2069, 857}}
```

Are there more elegant ways using Cases (or others)?

Comment: `pq[v_]:=And@@Map[PrimeQ,v]; Select[sol,pq]` ?

Comment: `sol // Select[AllTrue[PrimeQ]]`

Comment: Akku's solution will strictly select pairs of primes, while kglr's solution will pick out lists of primes of any length.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Cases[{__?PrimeQ}] @ sol
```

> `{{2063, 853}, {2069, 857}}`

Answer (score 11):

```
Cases[sol, {_?PrimeQ, _?PrimeQ}]

(*   {{2063, 853}, {2069, 857}}   *)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Using `Pick`:**

```
Pick[sol, And @@@ PrimeQ@sol]
```

**Using `Select` with `NoneTrue`:**

```
Select[sol, NoneTrue[CompositeQ]]
```

**Using `Divisors`:** (*ignore me*)

```
Cases[Map[Divisors, sol, {2}], {{1, a_}, {1, b_}} :> {a, b}]
```

> {{2063, 853}, {2069, 857}}

---

For larger lists, a better way would be to look at the first column only and select conformant entries as a first step. This smaller list can then be checked for the primes in the second column.

```
SeedRandom[3];
sol2 = RandomInteger[{1, 1000}, {100, 2}];
Pick[sol2, PrimeQ[sol2[[All, 1]]]]
```

> {{491, 41}, {727, 215}, {751, 292}, {17, 483}, {673, 580}, {137,
> 953}, {457, 670}, {163, 858}, {83, 295}, {127, 399}, {11,    336},
> {677, 941}, {827, 531}, {137, 200}, {307, 120}, {599,    313}, {431,
> 246}, {263, 442}, {643, 458}, {463, 930}}

```
Pick[%, PrimeQ[%[[All, 2]]]]
```

> {{491, 41}, {137, 953}, {677, 941}, {599, 313}}

To check validity using @swish 's variation from the comments:

```
Select[sol2, AllTrue[PrimeQ]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.000124665, {{491, 41}, {137, 953}, {677, 941}, {599, 313}}}

This will get more efficient as sublist size increases. For this example, `AbsoluteTiming` reported `0.0000561443` vs `0.000124665` for a factor of `2.22043` improvement that depends on the density of primes present, but is an expected outcome for random numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Using `GroupBy` and `Lookup`:

```
Lookup[GroupBy[sol, AllTrue[PrimeQ]], True] // AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.0000272, {{2063, 853}, {2069, 857}}}*)
```

Another way using `Position` and `Extract`:

```
Extract[#, Position[#, {__?PrimeQ}]] &@sol // AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.0000478, {{2063, 853}, {2069, 857}}}*)
```

Another way using the resource function `PositionedCases`:

```
Normal[ResourceFunction["PositionedCases"][sol, {__?PrimeQ}]][[All, 2]] // AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.0020174, {{2063, 853}, {2069, 857}}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{2063, 853}, {2066, 855}, {2069, 857}, {2072, 859}};
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
Join @@ SequenceSplit[list, {{a_, b_} /; ! PrimeQ[a] || ! PrimeQ[b]}]
```

{{2063, 853}, {2069, 857}}